# Wiringpi under Python shell

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, wiringpi

I repeat here a simplified version of a question for which I received no reply:
 
I installed wiringpi on my RaspberryPi 3 Python 3.4.
 
I can run the wiring commands (like i2cdetect) under the raspberrypi command line, but I can not make it work in the Python shell.
 
I have tried various installations and imports, but it does not appear to become a recognized module by the Python shell.  
 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Show us what you've tried - much better than having us guess at a solution only to have you say you tried it already/ Have you tried any of the tutorials out there?

Comment: How did you install it - via pip3? You need first to install pip3 for python 3 using `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` then install wiringpi via `sudo pip3 install wiringpi`

Comment: As I have done lots of experiments, I am not sure anymore what I did. I can import wiringPi onto the Python shell, but from that point on I do not know how to proceed. (example run the i2cdetect, that runs ok on Raspberry Pi command line and can communicate with a I2C slave) – samtal 10 hours ago

Comment: You're going to have to do better than that here. Show your install command line. Show your command to start and import it. Show at least one example of what you've tried - if not more. List error messages.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of googling and testing, I found the ultimate solution, as can be seen [here](http://jtecheng.com/?p=959).

The problem is that Python 3 does not seem to support the [SMBus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Bus) (or vice versa), which is the standard Rasbian I2C tool, and a complex tweaking was necessary to make it run under Python 3, as can be seen in the attached link.
As soon as I completed the tweak, all runs just fine.
The SMBus has a relatively large number of I2C commands for various data types.
Here is a code example from the SMBus site:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smbus

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)    # 0 = /dev/i2c-0 (port I2C0), 1 = /dev/i2c-1 (port I2C1)

DEVICE_ADDRESS = 0x15      #7 bit address (will be left shifted to add the read write bit)
DEVICE_REG_MODE1 = 0x00
DEVICE_REG_LEDOUT0 = 0x1d

#Write a single register
bus.write_byte_data(DEVICE_ADDRESS, DEVICE_REG_MODE1, 0x80)

#Write an array of registers
ledout_values = [0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff]
bus.write_i2c_block_data(DEVICE_ADDRESS, DEVICE_REG_LEDOUT0, ledout_values) 
bus.read_byte(DEVICE_ADDRESS)
```

Lots of thanks to [JTech Engineering](http://jtecheng.com/?p=959) for this contribution!